# AWS Databricks cluster not starting : Failed to init

Tags: databricks, aws-databricks

Bootstrap Timeout:
[id: InstanceId(i-04bd85c1b17328b96), status: INSTANCE_INITIALIZING, workerEnvId:WorkerEnvId(workerenv-2273350004125125-ce5d7a3b-cda1-4494-aa7f-c1bcea16ce04), lastStatusChangeTime: 1686032804843, groupIdOpt Some(0),requestIdOpt Some(0602-133108-aafe0zdp-52d45615-a2ac-462e-8),version 1] with threshold 700 seconds timed out after 700855 milliseconds. Please check network connectivity from the data plane to the control plane.

Comment: please provide more information about your setup - private link or no, etc.